# does PCA give us the ordered list from features from the most important to less?

Tags: r, pca

I have a general question about principle component analysis:
I know PCS give us a direction that data have the most variation in that direction. I am wondering can PCS give us an order for features from the most important one to the least?
For example if I have 8 features f1,...,f8, it gives me f5 is the most important then f3 then f8 then f4 and ...
If yes what function should I call in R?

Answer (score 1):

Each principal component is a transformation of length p. If you have eight features PCA will produce 8 principal components, each of length 8 in which each element is a scalar for features 1 through 8. The elements of the the principal components are in the same order as your variables. The larger the absolute value of the element with the corresponding index (i = 1 ... p), the greater that variable contributes to the transformation of that PC. The first PC is usually the most significant transformation, followed by PC2, and so on.

Comment: this is a concept that it is really hard for me to understand. so you say a variable with bigger coefficient (in PCA1) is more important?

Comment: See the loadings. They will give information on the importance of the features. Also, if you have doubts about *concepts*, ask [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), SO is for doubts about *code*. See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87037/which-variables-explain-which-pca-components-and-vice-versa) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108148/pull-out-most-important-variables-from-pca).

Comment: is there any group for functional linear registration?

Comment: @user9272398 To answer your first questions, that variable is indeed more important, but only to PC1. (unless the same variable has a large absolute coefficient within PC2, and so on.) You can look at eigenvalues to determine how many PCs your data require in order to explain the proportion of the variance your interested in explaining.